# JDBC connectivity CODE Error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a project that requires Java-Mysql connectivity.
I have been trying to connect two tables from one button to give me an output in four JLabels and a JTextArea.

It shows there is an error in my SQL syntax. [image: Error Img]

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  try {
    Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:Mysql://localhost/nami", "root", "123456");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();

    String S =
        "Select mobile,state,mobile,email,job from signup where email = " + "mil@gmail.com" + ";";

    String P = "Select INFORMATION FROM pinfo where email = " + "mil@gmail.com" + ";";

    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(S);
    ResultSet rs2 = st.executeQuery(P);
    while (rs.next()) {
      String JOB = rs.getString("JOB");
      String state = rs.getString("state");
      String no = rs.getString("mobile");
      String email = rs.getString("email");

      jLabel5.setText(JOB);
      jLabel16.setText(state);
      jLabel31.setText(no);
      jLabel7.setText(email);
    }

    while (rs2.next()) {
      String info = rs.getString("information");
      jTextArea1.setText(info);
    }

    con.close();
    st.close();
    rs.close();
    rs2.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error" + e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `WHERE` statement you must quote the actual value by surrounding it with single quotes `'`. This is explained in MySQL docs chapter 
[9.1.1 String Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html). Your code should be:

```
String P = "Select INFORMATION FROM pinfo where email = 'mil@gmail.com';";
```

Please learn about the prepared statemenets if you plan to use JDBC. See [Using Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the **single quotes** around the email id. Try below,

```
String S= "Select mobile,state,mobile,email,job from signup where email = 'mil@gmail.com';";

String P = "Select INFORMATION FROM pinfo where email = 'mil@gmail.com';";
```